# SIP/HTTP Converged app INVITE not being sent out

Tags: java, sip

I have a simple Web Servlet and a Simple Sip Servlet. In the Web Servlet, I create a SIP INVITE request (using SipFactory reference) and do a request.send()

However, instead of the packet going over the network, it seems to appear as a request to the SipServlet in doInvite().

My application uses annotations and is deployed in IBM WAS Liberty and is based almost a 100% on a mobicents clicktodial demo.

The Demo code when deployed seems to work, but that has sip.xml and web.xml.

So either I am doing something really stupid, or in SIP 1.1 the behaviour is that an HTTP servlet when sending an INVITE will only send it out to another SIP servlet which would then need to proxy the packet out to the intended destination ?

The demo where the INVITE works from the HTTP servlet is located at

https://github.com/deruelle/mobicents/tree/master/servers/sip-servlets/sip-servlets-examples/click-to-call

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding a DAR configuration for the default router to let my app "ROUTE_BACK" on an INVITE.

I don't really understand the DAR very well, but at least I know where to look for more info now.

I believe the demo application which worked was using the 1.0 servlet specification, although it did not have anything special in its sip.xml which would make it look like it was.